# excel vertical lookup with a modified test

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have data in one sheet (let us call it the results sheet) that has the coursework name in column B which is sometimes (but not always) followed by the date. For example I might have:

```
long lab
```

or

```
metals lab 27 Oct 2016
```

I use vlookup to match the coursework name against a table in another sheet (let us call it the table sheet) to discover which sheet the marks are in. For example:

```
coursework    tab name
------------------------
long lab      longlab
metals lab    metalslab
```

If every piece of coursework had a date at the end I could use something like

```
=vlookup(left(b7,len(b7)-12), tablesheet!$A$1:$B$10, 2, FALSE)
```

where the date is assumed to take 12 characters. But some pieces of coursework lack the date.

What I would like to be able to do is something like

```
=vlookup(b7, tablesheet!$A$1:$B$10 & "*", 2, FALSE)
```

by which I mean, put a wild card at the end of the coursework names in the table sheet when matching against the coursework name in the results sheet. But this is not a legal construct.

Does anyone know of a trick for doing this?

Comment: Assuming the dates *always* start with a number, then this should work for you: `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(LEFT(B7,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},B7&1234567890))-1)),tablesheet!$A$1:$B$10,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks. I see the idea. Some course titles include numbers unfortunately, such as "tensile test 1" and "tensile test 2".

Answer (score 0):

Just put this formula inside the **IF** formula. For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(B7,1)),VLOOKUP(LEFT(B7,LEN(B7)-12), tablesheet!$A$1:$B$10, 2, FALSE),VLOOKUP(B7,tablesheet!$A$1:$B$10, 2, FALSE))
```

IF formula checks wether text contains data (which ends with number) or not.

Comment: Thanks. As some coursework names end in a number, this would need some tweaking. If the string ends in 2016 or 2017 it will be a date, so I could probably modify your right() statement to trap that.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, BTW, you can use RIGHT(B7,4) to ensure last 4 characters are number